# copy consolidated element value to other cube (TM1 SERVER)

Tags: cognos, cognos-tm1

I have two cubes here, first cube that have a dimension STORE WHICH HAVE ELEMENTS SUCH AS
-branch(CONSOLIDATED)
-regency(CONSOLIDATED)
-Subdistrict(CONSOLIDATED)
-village(CONSOLIDATED)
-store(LEAF ELEMENT),
also have a measure value ( amount ), period (month and year)
and the second cube have a dimension subdistrict that consist of branch(consolidated) and subdistrict(element)
... and the problem is..
I want to copy consolidated amount of subdistrict from first cube and put it to dimension subdistrict in second cube....
Why not use rule? because STORE elements and SUBDISTRICT element are dynamic dimension so i can't mention all of store data and subdistrict data in rule.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Without rules, and if you are not using [CellGetN](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMR4U_10.2.1/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.tm1_ref.10.2.0.doc/r_tm1_ref_tifun_cellgetn.html) in TurboIntegrator to get a cell's numerical value, I think the best tool you can use is `CTRL+C`.

P.S. You should at least tell which tool you're planning to use (Perspectives on Excel, TI Processes, etc.)